# Bash Exit Status codes for Ping

Tags: bash, loops, ping, hosts

I am working on a small script that checks if a host is up or down.

```
until [ "$STATUS" -eq "0" ]
do
ping -c 1 192.168.0.3
echo The host is down
STATUS=`echo $?`
done
```

It is supposed to change the status to 0 if it pings a host that is up and exit the until loop. But it doesnt. Even if I echo out the value of $? the value is always zero.

Can anyone help me figure this out please? :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `echo The host is down` after `ping` command. So `$?` takes the exit status of the `echo` command not the `ping` command.

```
ping -c 1 192.168.0.3
STATUS=$?
if [ $STATUS -ne 0 ]; then
   echo "The host is down"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks I used code supplied in a video tutorial and it seemed to work for the instructor but not sure why it didnt work for me. Maybe because I am on OSX and he is on Red Hat?

    until [ "$STATUS" -eq "0" ]
    do
 ping -c 1 192.168.0.11
 STATUS=`echo $?`
 echo The host is down
    done

Comment: Hmm kinda lost some formatting there. but I basically just put the command substitution above the echo and that worked :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You placed echo after saving the status that's why you always get 0:

```
ping -c 1 192.168.0.3
echo The host is down  ## Always changes $? to 0
STATUS=`echo $?`
```

One better way to do it could be:

```
until ping -c 1 192.168.0.3; do
    echo "The host is down"
done
```

Longer version:

```
until ping -c 1 192.168.0.3; STATUS=$?; [ "$STATUS" -eq "0" ]; do
    echo "The host is down"
done
```

Comment: im not quite sure what you mean. The STATUS variable is set and then uses command substitution to set the value of status to the current exit status. But even when I use a valid/invalid ip address it doesnt make any difference to the output

Comment: @NATHANC Just running echo after ping changes $? that's why STATUS always saves 0. Command substitution `` `echo $?` `` has nothing to do with it and is also unnecessary. Please try my examples.

Comment: Hi, yes I understand my example isnt the most efficient it is merely to help me understand and learn bash at the moment I am following the CBT vids. This has really helped me learn though :) thank you very much